# Using the Squeezing Theorem of Limits in Mathematica

Tags: assumptions

I wanted to compute the following limit

```
Limit[ρ, {α -> 0}, Direction -> "FromAbove", Assumptions -> 1 <= ρ <= 1 + α]
```

clearly this has the answer $\alpha$ by using the squeezing theorem. However, I don't know how to get the right answer from Mathematica.

Comment: I think this topic is too hard for current CASes. For example, Limit[\[Rho][\[Alpha]], \[Alpha] -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove", 
 Assumptions -> 
  ForAll[\[Alpha], \[Alpha] >= 0, 
   1 <= \[Rho][\[Alpha]] && \[Rho][\[Alpha]] <= 1 + \[Alpha]]] fails.

Comment: @user64494 But `Reduce[ForAll[\[Alpha], \[Alpha] >= 0, 
  1 <= \[Rho] && \[Rho] <= 1 + \[Alpha]]]` works just fine...

Comment: @Henrik Schumakher: So what? The question is unclearly formulated. The command  Limit[\[Rho], \[Alpha] -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove", 
 Assumptions -> 
  ForAll[\[Alpha], \[Alpha] >= 0, 
   1 <= \[Rho] && \[Rho] <= 1 + \[Alpha]]] produces [Rho] instead of 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
Limit[#, α -> 0] & /@ (1 <= ρ <= 1 + α)
Reduce[%]
(* ρ == 1 *)
```

Comment: Yes, but this is a little weird to me! Why the `Limit` doesn't use its assumptions? What is wrong with my implementation?

Comment: Is ρ treated as a function of  α in your code? Also the condition should be ForAll[\[Alpha], \[Alpha] >= 0, 
 1 <= \[Rho][\[Alpha]] && \[Rho][\[Alpha]] <= 1 + \[Alpha]] .

Comment: @H.R. `Limit[ρ, α -> 0, whatever options]` will always return `ρ`, regardless of what the actual options are. The reason is that `ρ` is independent of `α`, and therefore the limit is trivial. If you want a non-trivial limit, you'd have to use `ρ[α]` instead of `ρ`, to let MMA know `ρ` is a function of `α` rather than a constant. MMA is a piece of software, not a person, so it doesn't interpret intentions.

Comment: @user64494: `ρ` is not a function of `α` it is some constant which always lies in the aforementioned interval. Also, your assumptions does not does not solve the issue!

Comment: @H.R. Right, `ρ` lies in an interval with `α`-dependent interval boundaries. What AccidentalFourierTransform does is applying the limit to the interval boundaries.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: Yes, I got that. :) Why the down vote! :(

Comment: @H.R. I don't know; it's no from me! As a proof  and compensation, I'll vote up. =)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: Thanks future moderator. ;)

Comment: @H.R. Unlikely. I guess, even your vote won't change the tides... ;)